# Multiple functions returning promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an HTTP helper that returns a promise for each request. Sometimes those requests depend on each other. I am confusing myself into coding what I think are anti-patterns for this.

Normally when chaining promises you use `.then()`

```
function giveMeASimplePromise(){
     return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
          setTimeout( function(){
               console.log("I'm finishing a promise.");
               resolve();
          }, 3000 );
     });
}

giveMeASimplePromise().then( giveMeASimplePromise ).then( giveMeASimplePromise );

//prints 'I'm finishing a promise' 3 times spaced 3 seconds apart
```

But I am getting confused if there is a promise *within* one of those promises that needs to be part of the chain.

This is coming up for me because I have an HTTP helper function that returns a promise with each request. A couple of those requests depend on each other. And the whole process needs to return a promise to keep everything async.

```
function login( credentials ){
    //outer promise that's returned and either needs to resolve or reject based
    // on complete login cycle
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
        //inner promise checking for username/password match. can be rejected 
        // for several reasons.
        var checkCredentials = httpHelper.checkCredentials( credentials );
        checkCredentials.then( function(result){
            if ( result.credentialsMatch ){
                //another inner promise checking for privilege levels. never rejects.
                var checkPrivileges = httpHelper.getPrivileges( result.userID ); 
                getPrivileges.then( function(result) ){
                    if( result.privilege > 0 ){
                        //want this to resolve the entire chain
                        resolve();
                    }else{
                        //want this to reject the entire chain
                        reject('You do not have sufficient privileges.');
                    }
                }
            }else{
                reject('Incorrect username and/or password.');
            }
        }).catch( function(reason){
            reject( reason );
        });
    });
}

var credentials = { ... };
var loginResult = login( credentials ).then( function(value){
    console.log('Logged in successfully.');
}).catch( function(reason){
    console.log('Could not log in: ', reason);
})
```

That's an anti-pattern, right? It feels wrong.

Comment: Sorry - just left it out. The snippet is a simplification of something a little more interwoven.

Comment: Creating (and returning) promises in (possibly nested) `then` callbacks is totally fine. But you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed not need to create a promise with `new` when you already get a promise from a service you use. In that case, just use *that* promise and chain on it and finally return the chained promise.

When not using `new Promise` you obviously don't call `reject`. Instead `throw` within the `then` callback(s). Also the nested `then` calls should better be moved one level up so you get a flat `then` chain.

Here is how that could look:

```
function login(credentials) {
    return httpHelper.checkCredentials(credentials).then(function(result) {
        if (!result.credentialsMatch) throw "Wrong credentials!";
        return httpHelper.getPrivileges(result.userID); // Don't chain here, but return!
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.privilege <= 0) throw "You do not have sufficient privileges.";
    });
}
```

As you probably know, things look even simpler when you use `async/await` syntax:

```
async function login(credentials) {
    const result = await httpHelper.checkCredentials(credentials);
    if (!result.credentialsMatch) throw "Wrong credentials!";
    const result2 = await httpHelper.getPrivileges(result.userID);
    if (result2.privilege <= 0) throw "You do not have sufficient privileges.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of a *hypothetical* case which could be useful to anyone landin on this thread. Say if the `getPrivileges()` Promise does not resolve() to a value which could be validated in the second .then() , and instead returns a reject() with an error message, we could chain a `catch()` and check for the error message to determine the next action.